# Kodi doesn't play all formats.

Tags: kodi

I have run not only into video not playing, but the heads or DVD-style covers that are the pictorial representation for shows, movies and such do not load. Can anyone tell me, if I purchase these codecs for RPi3, that this will fix the problem? It happens to most of them that load in a page - not always - when it doesn't load the front it sometimes loads the seasonal covers. It will, however, load synopsis and background fan art. What gives?

Comment: Could you tell us the file formats you are trying to use?